# Options for online fitting

Tags: bike-fit

anyone know of good options for a remote/virtual fitting service?

I'm not looking for an app, but rather personalized fitters that have moved to remote during Covid.

Thanks.

Comment: ''Is it possible to get a good bike fit remotely?'' Is my question. It is a hands-on experience that is vastly aided by expensive fitting equipment and good technical setup you are not likely to have at home

Comment: Fair question...I'm wondering a variant of it which is: is a substandard "virtual" fitting better than nothing. :)